# Keras multiply parallel layers' outputs with constrained weigths

Tags: keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have 3 parallel MLPs and want to obtain the following in Keras:

```
Out = W1 * Out_MLP1 + W2 * Out_MLP2 + W3 * Out_MLP3
```

where Out_MLPs are output layer of each MLP and have dimension of (10,) and W1, W2 and W3 are three trainable weights (floats) where they satisfy the following condition:

```
W1 + W2 + W3 = 1
```

What is the best way to implement this with Keras functional API? What if we had N parallel layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to apply a softmax on a set of learnable weights, in order to grant that they sum up to 1.

We initialize our learnable weights in a custom layer. this layer receives the output of our MLPs and combines them following our logic `W1 * Out_MLP1 + W2 * Out_MLP2 + W3 * Out_MLP3`. the output will be a tensor of shape (10,).

```
class W_ADD(Layer):

    def __init__(self, n_output):
        super(W_ADD, self).__init__()
        self.W = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.uniform(shape=[1,1,n_output], minval=0, maxval=1),
            trainable=True) # (1,1,n_inputs)

    def call(self, inputs):

        # inputs is a list of tensor of shape [(n_batch, n_feat), ..., (n_batch, n_feat)]
        # expand last dim of each input passed [(n_batch, n_feat, 1), ..., (n_batch, n_feat, 1)]
        inputs = [tf.expand_dims(i, -1) for i in inputs]
        inputs = Concatenate(axis=-1)(inputs) # (n_batch, n_feat, n_inputs)
        weights = tf.nn.softmax(self.W, axis=-1) # (1,1,n_inputs)
        # weights sum up to one on last dim

        return tf.reduce_sum(weights*inputs, axis=-1) # (n_batch, n_feat)
```

in this dummy example, I create a network that has 3 parallel MLPs

```
inp1 = Input((100))
inp2 = Input((100))
inp3 = Input((100))
x1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp1)
x2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp2)
x3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp3)
x1 = Dense(10, activation='linear')(x1)
x2 = Dense(10, activation='linear')(x2)
x3 = Dense(10, activation='linear')(x3)
mlp_outputs = [x1,x2,x3]
out = W_ADD(n_output=len(mlp_outputs))(mlp_outputs)

m = Model([inp1,inp2,inp3], out)
m.compile('adam','mse')

X1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,100))
X2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,100))
X3 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,100))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))

m.fit([X1,X2,X3], y, epochs=10)
```

as you can see this is easily generalizable in case of N parallel layers

Comment: Thanks Marco, this is great but I am wondering about softmax. Is it better to use constraints or other alternatives? In Softmax, only one output would be close to 1 and others close to 0, right?

Comment: softmax is the better and cleaner solution you have. no, the output constraints are not a problem... think at every multiclass NN and the relative degree of uncertainty related to the results. you can also test it by your self  tf.nn.softmax([0.3,0.9,0.8], axis=-1). let me know

Comment: Thanks, my remaining question is: "Is it possible to avoid concatenation?"

Comment: you can play and adjust the code provided. I use concatenation because it enables to manage dimensionality easily. I don't see any problem using it... don't forget to accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run the code as is but it gives this error: ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32_ref for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Adam/Variable/m/Initializer/zeros:0", shape=(1, 1, 3), dtype=float32)'

Comment: I have TF 2.2 and with tf.keras I have no problem... https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1idaURj-GSci7IgBRVOVqkPFMd1pgBf-P?usp=sharing

Comment: You are right, it was version issue. I have accepted your answer. BTW, how we can print out these 3 weights after training.

Comment: Great!!! following our example, these are the raw weights m.get_weights()[-1]. to get them in the range [0-1], as in the layer computation, the softmax do the job tf.nn.softmax(m.get_weights()[-1])